# Second-order differential equations application

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for applications of second-order linear differential equations aside from mechanics, economics and electrical circuits.  I was given hints to look on Ecology or other physics fields but it seems rather difficult to find something.

Can you point me to some other examples?

Comment: There are a lot of examples in physics. For example, the sound of a drum is given by the eigenvalue problem $\Delta u + \lambda u = 0$. Read a little about the Laplace operator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator), it appears in an enormous number of physical contexts.

Comment: Also Lotka-Volterra prey-predator system is a good example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation.

Comment: Lookup any of these (not to give preference to wikipedia):
- Maxwell's equations for electrodynamics
- Schrodingers' equation
- Fokker-Planck diffusion equation

Comment: @Jon: I think the Lotka-Volterra system is neither linear nor second order in the given form.

Comment: @WillieWong: Right, I was off the mark.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to point out that I was looking for one-variable equations. Looks like somehow I ignored completely unidimensional PDE.